# Restoring definitions and macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to restore macros in C, so that you can define a new macro, under which name probably other macros are already defined, and redefine it with the previous value?

so that when new defined macros are deleted and eventually redefined macros are resetted to its previous state?

Example:

```
// a macro parameter used in a library
#define size 10
#include <library/use_size.h>

//here the command/pragma to save the definitions
    #define size (100 / sizeof(size_t))
    // some use of size ...
//here the command/pragma to reset the definitions

#include <library/allocator_with_size.h>

#undef size

// use size as a variable name
size_t size = 0;
//...
size += 123;
```

Edit: I do not want to use `#undef`, because it does not restore old macros. Also, if you have many macros, eg for using them in a X-macro-list (in a long repetitive code/declaration of constant arrays and structs), it looks ugly, if there are many `#undef` directives.

Comment: How about `#undef`?

Comment: #undef size    ....

Comment: Also, there's no "previous state" to macros. They are either defined or they are not.

Comment: I know undef, and it makes very unreadable code.

Comment: Macros in general tend to make code harder to read. But pragmas won't make it easier either. Also, the usual naming-scheme for macros is all upper-case letters, like `SIZE`. Makes it a little easier to recognize macros and also to not mix with variables or other symbols. Lastly, what is the macros *used* for? Why do you need it? Can't it be a `const` variable instead?

Comment: @Some programmer dude OldProgrammer I want to keep old macros, undef destroys all macros, even if you defined it twice. Maybe I defined size and then I define size again, then the old definition of size is lost.

Comment: What? No, `#undef` only removes the specified macro, not all of them. And you can't define the same macro twice, it's an error. Just do `#undef SIZE` when you don't need the macro anymore.

Comment: @Some programmer dude It should only be an example, to describe the situation. I maybe want to include a file, which does not care about definitions of other headers. And I usually use capitalized macros, but I maybe use SIZE in an enum.

Comment: #defining some macro again not always gives an error, clang only spits a warning.

Comment: Anyway, no compiler that I know of allows you to "push" the current preprocessor state or macros and later "pop" it. I'm fairly confident that it's not really allowed considering that it's not allowed to have multiple definitions of the same macro (which will make the code even *more* unreadable!)

Answer (score 10):

Ok I researched myself and found the pragmas `push_macro` and `pop_macro`, supported by clang, gcc and visual c++. I use clang, so it is no problem to use it. The disadvantage: it does not reduce the line-count if you want to restore multiple macros ¹, but it restores the macros and can be encapsulated:

```
#pragma push_macro("size")
    #define size (100 / sizeof(size_t))
#pragma pop_macro("size")
```

**Notes:**

¹ I defined multiple macros and tried to restore them with:

```
#pragma push_macro("size", "key", "name")
    // define them all
#pragma pop_macro("size", "key", "name")
```

But that is not implemented into the compilers yet. So for each macro there must be a seperate line to do this.

Comment: If you can do it in a #pragma, you can set up macros to allow multiple calls per line (doesn't work in MSVC; they're all messed up; though in theory they have a way to do it, their nonstandard pragma variant emits garbage for push_macro and pop_macro).  But this sounds a bit dangerous... if you're _not_ doing this in headers, why do you need the pop?  No other unit will see your redefined variants (and even if you do "need" it, you might could just rearrange code).  If you _are_, aren't you designing something fragile anyway?  (Rather than pop-ing in a header, shouldn't you not collide?)